# convert between different time zones

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, database-trigger

i want to make mysql Trigger convert between different time zones dynamically stored in database, what i mean i want to make trigger convert "course_start" in current format from "student_time_zone" to "teacher_time_zone" and insert into 'course_start_teacher_timezone'

[image]